# Why am I not seeing any lint error for hard coded text in android studio

Tags: android, lint

While reading on Lint tool I tried to test it on a simple project in android studio. Just created a new project with empty activity. The xml for the mainActivity is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Mainactivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

From android studio when I try to run Analyze>>Inspect Code>> the whole project; it shows the following in inspection result: [inspection result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6lu.jpg)

Shouldn't it also be showing the warning for hard-coded text("Hello World!") which is used for TextViews text?

As I wasn't getting the warning so I tried to change the severity level in settings>> editor>>Inspection as shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvkBx.jpg). But still, the inspection result is the same. No warning or errors.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not getting any hint, can you try the "reset" option that is on top of your setting screen according to your screen-shot ?

Comment: @akshay :I have done -"reset to empty" and then "restore defaults"..still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a reason which is weird. If I move the exclamation sign from the text("Hello World!") then it shows the error/warning. For some reason with the exclamation sign added to the text Lint doesn't show a warning for hardcoded text.

Comment: Yes you found exact case, I tried to check that is there any rule in lint or in TextView class for hardcoded string "Hello World!" but still not getting any idea.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the string `Hello World!` is [a special case](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/HardcodedValuesDetector.kt#84):

```
if (value == "Hello World!") {
    // This is the default text in new templates. Users are unlikely to
    // leave this in, so let's not add warnings in the editor as their
    // welcome to Android development greeting.
    return
}
```